# How to change style of an HTML tag *inside* an Angular component?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an Angular component, defined as follows:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rdc-dynamic-icon-button',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-icon-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-icon-button.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicIconButtonComponent {
  @Input() label = '';
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() fileType = '';
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClick() {
    this.click.emit();
  }
}
```

This is the component template:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">
  <img src="../../../assets/icons/{{icon}}.{{fileType}}" />
  <span class="buttonLabel">{{ label }}</span>
</button>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
button {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #0066cc;
  border: 1px solid #0066cc;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 1em;
}
// The button's icon
img {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

Now I’m using this button component twice in a row, with two different icons:
[image: two buttons]

To get the icon on the left to be properly aligned with the button label, I used the CSS property `bottom: 5px`. But with this button being dynamic in nature, of course this CSS rule will always be used, whichever icon ends up being passed to the component.

In the screenshot, you can see that the heart icon in the right button is pushed too far up by `bottom: 5px`.

What can I do to change only the second button’s CSS property to vertically position the heart icon better? Here is the template:

```
<rdc-dynamic-icon-button
        label="Share this page"
        icon="share_icon"
        fileType="svg"
        class="results-descr-button1"
      ></rdc-dynamic-icon-button>
      <rdc-dynamic-icon-button
        label="Save this page"
        icon="fill-1"
        fileType="svg"
        class="results-descr-button2"
      ></rdc-dynamic-icon-button>
```

A colleague suggested using [ngStyle] but from what I’ve seen by googling, that’s only useful when selecting a specific HTML tag and cannot be used to select a CSS selector *inside* an Angular component. I may be wrong.

Comment: Do you have control over the size (width / height, not bytes) of the icons displayed in the component?

Comment: They are SVGs, so yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion things you can do:

- Make sure all icons are the same size (for example style `img` to have constant width and height)
- Use [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to style template inside `button`. That way you can align / justify your items to be vertical or horizontal centered.

Comment: This made sense to me. Worked out fine when I tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding an `id=""` to the second button and adjusting the CSS to only that button? Like so:

```
<rdc-dynamic-icon-button
  id="saveBtn"
  label="Save this page"
  icon="fill-1"
  fileType="svg"
  class="results-descr-button2"
></rdc-dynamic-icon-button>
```

In your CSS:

```
rdc-dynamic-icon-button#saveBtn {
    bottom: 0; /* or whatever value you find works */
}
```

If that doesn't work you can try further refining the scope:

```
rdc-dynamic-icon-button#saveBtn img {
    bottom: 0; /* or whatever value you find works */
}
```

Or use the `class` attached to the second button as a refiner:

```
.results-descr-button2 img {
    bottom: 0; /* or whatever value you find works */
}
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you for the suggestion. The main issue remains, however. In the code examples I gave, we deal only with these two icons. However, this dynamic button is meant to be reusable for an arbitrary number of of icons/labels. I guess what I’m looking for is a universal way to perfectly vertically center the icons alongside the label next to it, regardless of minor variance in icon size.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1) Add a input variable which is boolean to define if you need to add padding or not

2) based on the input variable add an ngClass to the img tag

3) Have a separate class with only bottom padding

The final code will look something like this:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'rdc-dynamic-icon-button',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-icon-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-icon-button.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicIconButtonComponent {
  @Input() label = '';
  @Input() icon = '';
  @Input() fileType = '';
  @Input() addPadding = false;
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter<any>();

  onClick() {
    this.click.emit();
  }
}
```

This is the component template:

```
<button (click)="onClick()">
  <img src="../../../assets/icons/{{icon}}.{{fileType}}" [ngClass]="{ 'bottomPadding': addPadding }" />
  <span class="buttonLabel">{{ label }}</span>
</button>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
button {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: white;
  color: #0066cc;
  border: 1px solid #0066cc;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 1em;
}
// The button's icon
img {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
}
bottomPadding {
  bottom: 5px;
}
```

Here is how you can use it:

```
<rdc-dynamic-icon-button
    label="Share this page"
    icon="share_icon"
    fileType="svg"
    class="results-descr-button1"
  ></rdc-dynamic-icon-button>
  <rdc-dynamic-icon-button
    label="Save this page"
    icon="fill-1"
    fileType="svg"
    class="results-descr-button2"
    addPadding="true"
  ></rdc-dynamic-icon-button>
```